# python tifffile.imsave to save 3 images as 16bit image stack

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff

I'm trying to save a numpy array as 16bit image stack using tifffile.imsave. This works perfectly fine for 1,2, or >= 5 images. However, if I try to save 3 or 4 images in one stack, image readers (such as ImageJ) interpret the images as rgb-channels, or as rgb-channels plus one gray value channel, respectively. Is there a way to avoid this e.g. by adding the right flags or tags?

```
import numpy as np
from tifffile import imsave

data = np.random.rand(3, 301, 219).astype(np.uint16)
imsave('myFileName.tif', data)
```

Comment: Specify the color space:`photometric='minisblack'`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.